# Convertir a minusculas el texto de un EditText mientras se escribe

Tags: java, android-studio, xml

No encuentro manera de que no se puedan escribir mayusculas, necesito que siempre sean minusculas

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/correo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
        android:hint="skynet@midominio.com"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColorHint="@color/ColorGray"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"/>
```

Comment: ¿Intentaste con Java? ¿podrías agregar a tu pregunta el código Java de este Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasa el texto a una variable, lo conviertes a minúsculas y lo estableces en el campo:

```
String tolowercase = name.getText().toLowerCase();
       text.setText(tolowercase);
```

Eso es.